# How do I find the resolution of my display panel?

Tags: display-resolution

I do not want the resolution I am running at but the actual resolution of my laptop's display panel. For example, if I have **set a 1600x900** resolution on a **1920x1080 display**, I want a command that outputs **1920x1080** and **not 1600x900**.

Comment: You can find your answer in this link:
[Ubuntu official blog page about resolution change.](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/look-resolution.html.en)

Comment: What is the output of `xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions'` ? You should set your display to use that resolution. (See the "Native Resolution" section of the link @Pooya Behravesh shared below).

Comment: @PJSingh `xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions'` gives me the current resolution I'm using and not the actual resolution of the panel. Also, what link are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

So.. I posted this question because I was skeptical about the resolution of my display panel because the display seemed a less sharper. It looks like all the linux commands give only the current resolution that we are running at and not the resolution of the panel itself.

I got over this issue by simply creating a 1920x1080 chess board image in opencv and viewing it in fullscreen mode. I could see every pixel so I was able to conclude that I had a 1920x1080 panel.